# Using drawInRect inside a c method not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, drawrect

I have this code, to draw some text inside a (so far) simple button:

```
UIImage *buttonImage(CGRect bounds, UIColor *fillColor, NSString *title) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, NO, 0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, bounds);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

    [title drawInRect:bounds withFont:PanelButtonFont];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

The problematic part is the `drawInRect`. It's simply not drawing my text. The font is correct, and I've tested this with normal font code there, so it's not that. I think perhaps it doesn't realise that I want it to draw it onto the image that it's producing?

Comment: you are getting the image before you drawing the title in it, thats all.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the order and get the image after you draw the text:

```
UIImage *buttonImage(CGRect bounds, UIColor *fillColor, NSString *title) {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, NO, 0);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, bounds);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

[title drawInRect:bounds withFont:PanelButtonFont];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

}